# How to extract GSTr 3B Report from Tally via ODBC

Tags: tally, tdl

I am able to extract sales data from tally via ODBC with the following code (Thaks to the user Adarsh Madrecha & Shweta Softwares)

```
Select Date,$Reference,$VouchertypeName,$PartyLedgerName,$$CollectionField:$Amount:1:LedgerEntries from RTSAllVouchers where $$IsSales:$VoucherTypeName"
TDL 
[Collection: RTSAllVouchers]  
Type: Voucher  
IsODBCTable: Yes  
Fetch : *, AllLedgerEntries.*, LedgerEntries.*
```

In similar way I want to extract

1. GSTR 3B report in excel via ODBC
2. Sales register in columnar format

Answer (score 0):

You can write a collection to fetch the required data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).